# IE does not detect inline style fast enough

Tags: html, css, elm

I'm creating an accordion module in Elm with an open/close animation. Initially, the accordion body has an attribute `style="height: 0"`. When opening the accordion I calculate the height of the hidden body and apply this by changing the attribute `style="height: <contentheight>"`. This is how I get the CSS transition to work.

After the accordion body has been fully expanded I set `style="height: auto"`. This is done using a `setTimeout` which matches the `transition-duration` time in the CSS. By doing this I allow the accordion body to resize automatically if its content changes after it has been opened.

In order to get the CSS transition working when I close the accordion, I first replace `auto` with a numeric value. I calculate the current height of the accordion body and put this in the `height`-style. After 1 millisecond (using `setTimeout`) I change to `height: 0`.

This works perfect in Chrome, but in IE 11 and Edge it fails about 80% of the time. If I increase the timeout to 50 ms it works every time, but of course there is a noticable input lag. If I use [Browser.Events.onAnimationFrame](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/browser/latest/Browser-Events#onAnimationFrame) instead of the 1ms timeout, it works in all three browsers, but since this requires a subscription in Elm it would be nice if there was a better way.

Are there other ways I can guarantee that IE and Edge will detect the attribute change if it's only there for 1ms?

Comment: `onAnimationFrame` is the right solution—subscriptions are based on the model, so you can make it so you only use that when needed, not just all the time if that is your issue with using the subscription. So I guess that is the question: what is the issue with using a subscription?

Comment: I want to reduce the amount of boilerplate code as much as possible. If using subscriptions the "parent app" must register subscriptions for all its accordions, and that just feels so unnecessary :D But perhaps that's the way it's got to be..

Comment: Yeah, in Elm boilerplate is sometimes unavoidable. Using a subscription here is really the only way—any duration is fragile (it may work in everything but IE on your system, but on others it may fail on other browsers too). Using pure CSS as per [SRack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60338259/722121) may sidestep the issue though.

Answer (score 3):

Why not add a class to the accordion when you open it and make the changes that way?

In the example below, using a tranformation on the `scaleY` property allows you to go from zero to auto height.

```js
document.getElementById('accordion-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('accordion').classList.toggle('expanded');
});
```

```css
#accordion {
  transform: scaleY(0); 
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: transform 300ms ease; // or however you want to handle this
}

#accordion.expanded {
  transform: scaleY(1); 
}
```

```html
<button id="accordion-button">Click me</button>

<ul id="accordion">
  <li>Some content</li>
  <li>Some more</li>
</ul>
```

That way everything will be handled by the CSS transition.

Comment: The thing is that CSS transitions only works with absolute values. Going from `auto` (or `min-content`) to `0` will instantly change the height, without an animation. That's why I have a temporary `height: <current-height>` before changing to `height: 0`

Comment: Thanks @EvenA.Rognlien, that's my bad - I'd thought `min-content` worked with transitions. I've updated with an alternative approach.

Comment: Thanks! I might give the `scaleY` a try :)